# Will Evolution still be included as an option?

Tags: 11.10, evolution

I see that Evolution is going to be replaced as the default email client by thunderbird ... I use thunderbird for my personal email, but I have Evolution set up to access my choir's IMAP email server, send out newsletters etc.

Will Evolution still be included as an option in 11.10 and following? Or will updating to 11.10 scrub my Evolution install? If the latter I will refuse the upgrade. Please advise immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are upgrading, then all your previous applications that you have installed will remain installed - if there is a newer version of the app, then the application will be upgraded.

Thus for evolution, your app will be upgraded - it will not be removed.

N.B. evolution remains in the repository - it is just  not installed by default in a new install.

**remember - as with all major upgrades - have a valid disk image tucked away, just incase the upgrade goes wrong**

Comment: Excellent answer! I just want to add: Users don’t be afraid when an app is “removed” from Ubuntu. It is just removed from the CD, but it remains installable via the official Ubuntu repositories (e.g. the Software Center)